# Using Lambda to Extend Table

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to move some logic out of the main query into a lambda so the main query is easier to read.

So I want to take logic like this:

```
T //columns: operation_Name
| extend path_Label = iif(operation_Name == '/', 'home', 'other')
//end up with columns: operation_Name, path_Label
```

And I'd like to move the `iif` logic into a lambda:

```
let translate_path = (operation_Name: string)
{
    iif(operation_Name == '/', 'home', 'other')
};
T
| extend path_Label = invoke translate_path(operation_Name)
```

Also tried:

```
let translate_path = (T:(operation_Name: string))`
{
    T | extend path_Label = iif(operation_Name == '/', 'home', 'other')
};
T
| invoke translate_path()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to add "invoke". Your first attempt should work just fine without it:

```
let translate_path = (operation_Name: string)
{
    iif(operation_Name == '/', 'home', 'other')
};
T
| extend path_Label = translate_path(operation_Name)
```